# UNITY Lose one life when player hits the water

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I want to change the number of lives every time the player hits the water. I wrote this code so far:

```
public var dieSound:AudioClip;
static var lives = 3;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
if(lives == 0)
{
Application.LoadLevel("menu");
}
}

public function OnGUI()
{
GUI.backgroundColor = Color.blue;
GUI.Button (Rect (10, 10, 100, 30), "Lives: " + lives);
}

function OnControllerColliderHit (hit : ControllerColliderHit)
{
if (hit.collider.tag == "Water")
{
// play dying sound
audio.PlayOneShot(dieSound);

// show mission fail UI
GameObject.Find("MissionTXT").guiText.enabled = true;
// wait until it's ended
yield WaitForSeconds(dieSound.length + 0.01);
transform.position = GameObject.FindWithTag("Respawn").transform.position;

if (transform.position == GameObject.FindWithTag("Respawn").transform.position)
{
GameObject.Find("MissionTXT").guiText.enabled = false;
lives = lives - 1;
}
}
}
```

The problem is that when the player hits the water, lives change from 3 to -120. I think that happens because the player is on the water for like 6-7 seconds. So character may hits the water 120 times until he goes back to the original position (Respawn position).

Can anyone help me with that please?

Comment: What would you like to know?

Comment: basically how can i prevent that? Is there any way when the player hits the water to lose only one life instead of 50 or 100?

Comment: Set a flag when you hit the water the first time.  Only deduct the life if the flag is not set.  Clear the flag  after you are sure you're not just hitting the water again repeatedly.  Or, redo your code in some way so that you don't hit the water 100 times in rapid succession, maybe by removing the player temporarily (he did die, right?).

Comment: How can I set a flag? do you mean a variable ? Thanks for your help, will try it

Comment: A flag is also known as a boolean variable. So set a boolean to true when you have lost a life and then check that boolean value, if it's true then don't deduct a life. If the boolean value is false, then minus a life.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is as follows:

1. On your water `GameObject`, add a `Collider` component. I would think that a `BoxCollider` would fit in this scenario. Don't forget to mark the `Is Trigger` checkbox.
2. On your player `GameObject`, add both a `RigidBody` and a `CharacterController` (since it looks like you are using the `CharacterController` component). Make sure to check the `RigidBody`'s `Is Kinematic` checkbox. Also, give your `GameObject` a meaningful tag like "Player".
3. Back to the water `GameObject`, add a new script that should look something like this:

   ```
   public class Water : MonoBehaviour {
       void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) {
           if(collider.CompareTag("Player")) {
               collider.SendMessage("Kill");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Back to the player `GameObject`, add a new script that should look something like this:

   ```
   public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
       public void Kill() {
           //Perform all necessary steps to kill the player such as...
           //Reduce the amount of lives by 1
           //Play the death sound
           //etc. etc. etc.
       }
   }
   ```

That's the "jist" of things, or this should at least get you started. Unity has some really good documentation and practically anything you need is there, you just have to know where to look. I'm not going to go in-depth of each thing I have mentioned above because as I've said, "Unity has some really good documentation." With that in mind, I highly recommend looking into each of the things I have mentioned. Hope this helps! =)